# In D3 Bubble Layout, Is there a way to listen to the name of a bubble and add interaction via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am buiding a D3 zoomable circle packed bubble layout like this one:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

I get the idea of json and manage to use my own json data.
However I would like to add interactivity to the bubbles via jQuery.

Something along the lines of:

```
$(IdOfCurrentBubble).mouseover(function({
    play sound (iDOfCurrentBubble.mp3);
    doStuff;
    doOtherStuff;
});
```

Comment: You don't need jquery for that: `d3.select("#IdOfCurrentBubble").on("mouseover", function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 1):

Why jquery?  Use `d3` to add the event handler:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
  .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); })
  .on("mouseover", function(d){ //<--here's your mouseover
    console.log(d.name);
  });
```

**EDITS**

Sorry, I missed the part about applying the function by ID.

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
  .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); })

d3.select("#IdOfCurrentBubble")
  .on("mouseover", someFunc);

function someFunc(){
  var myId = d3.select(this).attr('id');
  // use myId here
}
```

**EDITS 2**

If you want the `mouseover` only on the lowest level children, target them by class:

```
d3.selectAll(".node--leaf")
  .on("mouseover", someFunc);
```

Comment: Wow, that easy? But isn´t this a general statement for any circle? 
What if I want to have different functions depending on the name of the circle? Or is it just me and I don´t see where this is happening?

Comment: Ok. So i absolutely get the idea of 'someFunc()'. However the '("#IdOfCurrentBubble")' is not a variable in exitence. I just used it to clarify what I actually need. Do you know how to actually get the id? Or is the id actually important in this step? Wouldn´t it make sense to declare that whenever any low level bubble is hoverered, the id is read out and some code is executed?

Comment: @YuliyanIlev, what do you mean by "low level" bubble?  Do you only want the mouseover on the last "node--leaf" bubbles?

Comment: Yes, that´s what I meant. The lowest level in hierarchy which would be the white bubbles in the example.

Comment: Tried it. I think the
    var myId = d3.select(this).attr('id');
  console.log(myId);

part is causing the problem. 
I get the following error:

**[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'e.getAttribute(n)')

 (anonymous function) (d3.v3.min.js, line 1)**